# Find minimum number of equal MSBs with Matlab

Tags: matlab, bit

I perform measurements (of the same voltage) with an ADC  to find out real/noise-free resolution. A noise free resolution is the minimum number of most significant bits that are stable in all sample codes from a measurement.
The measurements are saved as binary codes to make them more apparent for visual inspection.

Example:
let's say sample codes are

**010111**01101

**010111**01110

**010111**10001

**010111**01100

Then the real resolution is 6 bit (equal MSBs marked with bold).  How do I find their number with Matlab?

Comment: How are your bits stored?

Comment: @AnderBiguri The measurement results are stored as binary codes to a text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your values in a vector in decimal form, for example by converting the binary digits in your question using the following:

```
>> vals = bin2dec({ '01011101101'; ...
                    '01011101110'; ...
                    '01011110001'; ...
                    '01011101100'})

vals =

   749
   750
   753
   748
```

which is equivalent to:

```
vals = [749; 750; 753; 748]
```

Then you could use this code to count the number of MSBs with `n` length binary numbers:

```
>> n=11;
>> MSBs = sum(~any(diff(dec2bin(vals,n))))

MSBs =

     6
```

---

**Description**

`dec2bin` converts to a char array with each row a number

`diff` finds the difference in binary digits (columns) between consecutive numbers

`any` asks if there are any columns which contain some differences

`~` alters the previous question to are there any columns which contain no differences

`sum` counts the number of columns (bits) with no differences

Comment: The code doesn't work ."Warning: The method char/diff will be removed in a future release. Use sym/diff instead."

Comment: @AndreyPro What version of Matlab are you using? It works perfectly fine on my R2017a version (which is the latest as of writing this comment) with a copy and paste. Be sure to clear any existing variables beforehand (in case `vals` and `n` exist already). I do not get any warning using these functions.

Comment: @AndreyPro Also, just because there is a warning here (which could be due to an earlier version of Matlab) doesn't necessarily mean "The code doesn't work". Does it still return the correct answer?

Comment: @AndreyPro Just tested and it also works fine (with no warnings) on R2015a, R2015b and R2016a.

Comment: Ok, got it. the key was to convert from cell to char array with `char`. The disavantage of this method that it takes in account differnce only with adjacent values. But it doesn't matter any mor, I found better way to find noise free resolution. I accept the anwser to reward your patience.

Comment: @AndreyPro The method does **not** "take into account difference *only* with adjacent values". It looks at **all** of the values and, from them, it gives one number indicating how many MSBs are the same over that set of values. So there is no disadvantage there like you say. I would suggest that you provide an answer of your own, or link, here if you found a better way to solve the problem.